# Collection<T>: why does it implement both IEnumerable and IEnumerable<T>?

Tags: c#, generics, collections

I know exactly the same question appears here on *StackOverflow*, nevertheless it does not quite answer my query.

If `ICollection<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`, which extends `IEnumerable`, why did programmers from *Microsoft* add `IEnumerable` as an interface that the `ICollection<T>` implements?

Isn't it exactly (semantically and implementation wise) the same as simply writing `ICollection<T> : IEnumerable<T>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It says it implements `IEnumerable` *because it implements `IEnumerable`.*

`IEnumerable<T>` inherits `IEnumerable`, but it can obviously provide no implementation. Classes that implement `IEnumerable<T>` *must also* implement `IEnumerable`, whether or not they *explicitly* state that they do so.

```
class Foo : IEnumerable<T> 
class Foo : IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable
```

With either case, you implement the members of both interfaces. The second class definition simply makes it obvious for those looking at the class and/or the documentation, which is a good thing. An inexperienced or otherwise uninformed reader might not know that `IEnumerable<T>` brings `IEnumerable` along with it. They might might not know that a class that implements `IEnumerable<T>` can be used where an `IEnumerable` is expected. This simply provides a bit more information to the reader, which can only be a good thing on average.

Comment: And tools like IlDasm and Reflector tend to show the 2nd longer form. Regardless from how it was written.

Comment: OK, so it is for readability rather than to provide any semantic/programming difference, is that correct?

Comment: Pretty much. It's optional to *list* the additional interfaces that are brought along. Implementations thereof are required either way.

Comment: @Bober02, Eric Lippert did a [nice write-up](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/04/04/so-many-interfaces.aspx) in his blog based on a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817369/why-does-does-it-really-listt-implement-all-these-interfaces-not-just-ilis).