# Why IList<T> extends both IEnumerable<T> and IEnumerable interfaces?

Tags: c#, .net

This is how looks `IList<T>` generic interface

```
public interface IList<T> : ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable
{
    T this[int index] { get; set; }

    int IndexOf(T item);

    void RemoveAt(int index);
}
```

Why `IList<T>` extends both `IEnumerable<T>` and `IEnumerable` interfaces?

`IEnumerable<T>` already have `IEnumerable`. Same thing is with `ICollection<T>` interface.

Comment: Actually it [didn't](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/mscorlib/src/System/Collections/Generic/IList.cs). MSDN is just a reference info and this interfaces added only for a clarity.

Comment: Perhaps just to make it explicit to someone looking at the declaration?

Comment: Probably a typo at MSDN page: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/ilist.cs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it didn't. You can see actual declaration on [Github](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/mscorlib/src/System/Collections/Generic/IList.cs):

> ```
> [TypeDependencyAttribute("System.SZArrayHelper")]
> #if CONTRACTS_FULL
> [ContractClass(typeof(IListContract<>))]
> #endif // CONTRACTS_FULL
> public interface IList<T> : ICollection<T>
> {
>     T this[int index] {
>         get;
>         set;
>     }
>
>     int IndexOf(T item);
>     void Insert(int index, T item);
>     void RemoveAt(int index);
> }
> ```

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6(v=vs.110).aspx) is just a reference info and this interfaces added only for a clarity.

Comment: I prefer [MS reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/ilist.cs,b19f71a84062554b).

Comment: I am actualy looking interface in visual studio .Net framework 4.6? Is here also added for clarity?

Comment: @Raskolnikov: your question was closed as [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817369/why-does-does-it-really-listt-implement-all-these-interfaces-not-just-ilis) by E. Lippert himself. It's worth reading that.